# Want to Persist entries in Mapstate in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am using MapState in CoProcessFunction in Flink.

Goal:
In CoProcessFunction, I want to make a mapState such that any entry that I insert into it, should persist.

Current Situation:

1. There is a stream of dtos from kafka stream.
2. From the stream, a dto arrives at x time and a key "abc" is stored in mapstate.
3. Then at any time>x, another dto arrives with the same key "abc", I want to check if this key has already been stored in mapstate or not.

Problem:
Now the problem is, on every element of the stream, a new Process Function is triggered, a new map is generated, so I can't access the previous Elements.

Possible but not applicable solution:
I can use a WindowProcessFunction, but it doesn't have the concept of timers. Since, I also need to set Timer based on every element, so this method in not applicable.

Main.java

```
dataStream1.connect(dataStream2)
        .keyBy((KeySelector<DTORetryMetadata, Object>) PrimaryKey::getPrimaryKey,
                (KeySelector<DTORetryMetadata, Object>) PrimaryKey::getPrimaryKey)
        .process(new FlinkStateStorageCoProcess());
```

FlinkStateStorageCoProcess.java

```
public class FlinkStateStorageCoProcess extends KeyedCoProcessFunction<Object, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient MapState<String, DTORetryMetadata> updatedMap;
    private transient MapState<String, DTORetryMetadata> retriesMaxedOutMap;

    @Override
    public void processElement1(DTORetryMetadata dtoRetryMetadata, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Object, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata>.Context context, Collector<DTORetryMetadata> collector) throws Exception {
        if(Objects.nonNull(dtoRetryMetadata)) {
            collector.collect(dtoRetryMetadata);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("DtoRetryMetaData is null");
        }

        String dtoRetryMetaDataId = (String) context.getCurrentKey();

        if(updatedMap.contains(dtoRetryMetaDataId)) {
            updatedMap.remove(dtoRetryMetaDataId);
        } else {
            updatedMap.put(dtoRetryMetaDataId, dtoRetryMetadata);
            log.info("{} added to Flink Memory", dtoRetryMetaDataId);
            try {
                TriggerTimeHelper triggerTimeHelper = new TriggerTimeHelper();
                Long triggerTime = triggerTimeHelper.getTriggerTime(dtoRetryMetadata.getRetryNo());
                log.info("Trigger timer set at {} from {}", triggerTime, context.timestamp());
                context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(
                        context.timestamp() + triggerTime);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to add timer to DTO,Retry Mechanism Failure. ");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void processElement2(DTORetryMetadata dtoRetryMetadata, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Object, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata>.Context context, Collector<DTORetryMetadata> collector) throws Exception {
        if(Objects.nonNull(dtoRetryMetadata)) {
            collector.collect(dtoRetryMetadata);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("DtoRetryMetaData is null");
        }

        String dtoRetryMetaDataId = (String) context.getCurrentKey();

        System.out.println("BEFORE INSERT IN KAFKA");
        for(DTORetryMetadata dtoRetryMetadata1: updatedMap.values()) {
            System.out.println("ENTRY : " + dtoRetryMetadata1);
        }

        if(updatedMap.contains(dtoRetryMetaDataId)) {
            updatedMap.remove(dtoRetryMetaDataId);
        } else {
            updatedMap.put(dtoRetryMetaDataId, dtoRetryMetadata);
            try {
                TriggerTimeHelper triggerTimeHelper = new TriggerTimeHelper();
                Long triggerTime = triggerTimeHelper.getTriggerTime(dtoRetryMetadata.getRetryNo());
                context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(
                        context.timestamp() + triggerTime);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to add timer to DTO,Retry Mechanism Failure. ");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Object, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata, DTORetryMetadata>.OnTimerContext context, Collector<DTORetryMetadata> out) throws Exception {
        String key = (String) context.getCurrentKey();
        if (updatedMap.contains(key)) {
            DTORetryMetadata dtoRetryMetadata = updatedMap.get(key);

            if (dtoRetryMetadata.getRetryNo() >= dtoRetryMetadata.getMaxRetryNo()) {
                updatedMap.remove(key);
            } else {
                RetryKafkaProducer retryKafkaProducer = new RetryKafkaProducer();
                if (retryKafkaProducer.sendMessageWithHeader("", dtoRetryMetadata)) {
                    updatedMap.remove(key);
                } else {
                    updatedMap.put(key, dtoRetryMetadata);
                    try {
                        TriggerTimeHelper triggerTimeHelper = new TriggerTimeHelper();
                        Long triggerTime = triggerTimeHelper.getTriggerTime(dtoRetryMetadata.getRetryNo());
                        context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(
                                context.timestamp() + triggerTime);
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to add timer to DTO, Retry Mechanism Failure. ");
                    }

                    log.info("ACK Not Received, Updating state {}:{}", key, updatedMap.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        try {
            MapStateDescriptor<String, DTORetryMetadata> updatedMapDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor(
                    "updatedMapState", String.class, DTORetryMetadata.class);
            updatedMap = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(updatedMapDescriptor);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Flink state initialisation failed. "+ e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you've used MapState where ValueState would be more appropriate. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590659/2000823 will help clear things up.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411579/2000823.